# How to subset data frame using row & col indices stored in another data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame with numbers called ‘m_df’ and another logical data frame called ‘pos’. 
I saved the coordinates (row and col) of the TRUE values in another data frame (‘true_pos’)
and would like to extract the numbers corresponding to these coordinates from the m_df.
What would be the best way to do this, please?

```r
set.seed(123)
m <- matrix(rnorm(3*4), 3, 4)
m
#>            [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]
#> [1,] -0.5604756 0.07050839  0.4609162 -0.4456620
#> [2,] -0.2301775 0.12928774 -1.2650612  1.2240818
#> [3,]  1.5587083 1.71506499 -0.6868529  0.3598138

m_df <- as.data.frame(m)

pos <- (m_df < 0.36 & m_df > 0.0)
pos
#>         V1    V2    V3    V4
#> [1,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
#> [2,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
#> [3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE

true_pos <- which(pos==TRUE, arr.ind = TRUE)
true_pos
#>      row col
#> [1,]   1   2
#> [2,]   2   2
#> [3,]   3   4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can just use the matrix as row/column index for extracting the elements from either the 'data.frame' or `matrix`

```
m_df[true_pos]
```

Also, we don't need to convert to `row/col` index.  Here, just

```
m_df[pos]
```

is enough